# '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe like this:

```
        datetime          duration
0   2018-10-08 13:30:00    03:00
1   2018-10-08 16:40:00    00:11
2   2018-10-08 21:30:00    03:19
3   2018-10-09 03:21:00    04:27
4   2018-10-09 07:49:00    02:11
```

I try to extract the rows in day time or night time by the following:

```
import datetime as dt

mask = (df_sleep['datetime'].dt.time > dt.datetime.strptime('08:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')) & (df_sleep['datetime'].dt.time < dt.datetime.strptime('21:00:00', '%H:%M:%S'))
df_sleep.loc[mask]
```

But it shows up error as:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

do you have any good idea how to solve this problem? Do I have to convert the datetime to string or int?(which will be still difficult to compare with)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `between_time`

```
df.set_index('datetime').between_time('08:00','21:00').reset_index()
Out[351]: 
             datetime duration
0 2018-10-08 13:30:00    03:00
1 2018-10-08 16:40:00    00:11
```

Using `dt.hour` with your mask idea

```
mask=(df['datetime'].dt.hour>8)&(df['datetime'].dt.hour<21)
mask
Out[357]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: datetime, dtype: bool
```